# C# SQL Generator to execute the new T-SQL Window Functions in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I'm looking for a SQL Generator that can execute the new window aggregate functions that were released in SQL Server 2012.  I've already looked at Subsonic and LINQ, but haven't yet taken a look at NHibernate and some others.

As an example, using the syntax in Subsonic, I'd like to do the following:

```
var query = new Select(Aggregate.Avg("Revenue", "MovingAverageRevenue")
    .PartitionBy("Account_ID").OrderBy("Offset").RowsBetween(-5,-1)))
    .From("Purchases")
    .Where("MovingAverageRevenue")
    .IsGreaterThan(500);
```

Which would translate to something like:

```
SELECT Aggregates.MovingAverageRevenue
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(Revenue) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY Account_ID 
         ORDER BY Offset 
         ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MovingAverageRevenue
    FROM Purchases
) Aggregates 
WHERE Aggregates.MovingAverageRevenue > 500
```

A solution involving extending an existing ORM could also work, presumably.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know for sure, but I am willing to bet that Microsoft didn't take the time to implement such constructs in LINQ-to-SQL, as there wouldn't be a need for it if LINQ-to-SQL was already working well.

I can't say much about Subsonic.